# ftp: Illegal PORT command with ls on Linux, but not OS X?

Tags: linux, osx, ftp

I'm getting strange errors with `ftp` on Linux (Arch, to be more specific, as part of the `inetutils` package).  To be truthful, the reason I'm using the shell command is because all of my other clients are fussing up, and this seems useful for troubleshooting.

```
[user@machine ~]$ ftp ftp2.example.com
[ logging in ]
ftp> ls
500 Illegal PORT command (Virtual Traffic Manager FTP proxy).
502 Command not implemented (Virtual Traffic Manager FTP proxy).
ftp: bind: Address already in use
```

I've tried passive mode, but to no avail.  It'll do this:

```
ftp> passive
Passive mode on.
ftp> ls
227 Entered Passive Mode [numbers here]
```

And then I'll wait around for six minutes or so and kill the prompt.  Meanwhile, in an OS X terminal at a computer across the room:

```
Group-iMac-2:~ intern$ ftp ftp2.ftptoyoursite.com
[ logging in again ]
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> ls
229 Extended Passive Mode Entered (|||61644|)
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
drwxr-x---   5 user   group     4096 Oct 21  2013 directory_1
drwxr-x---   5 user   group     4096 Oct 22 11:46 directory_2
226 Transfer complete
```

Does this have something to do with extended passive mode?  If I'm not mistaken, the `epsv` command can help with that.  But I tried that under Linux, and get the same issues.

```
ftp> 
ftp> epsv
Use of EPRT/EPSV for IPv4: on.
ftp> ls
500 Illegal PORT command (Virtual Traffic Manager FTP proxy).
500 Illegal PORT command (Virtual Traffic Manager FTP proxy).
502 Command not implemented (Virtual Traffic Manager FTP proxy).
ftp: bind: Address already in use
ftp> passive
Passive mode on.
ftp> ls
227 Entered Passive Mode [ more numbers ]
```

It hangs there.  Overall, I'm finding myself a little clueless.  `curlftpfs` and `lftp` are giving me similar issues; Filezilla is timing out after its LIST command, too.  I could solve this by only accessing the site from OS X, but I'd prefer to do things from my own workstation.   Maybe I could `ssh` into that other computer... but I'm hoping there's an alternative.

Thanks for any insight or suggestions.

Comment: Enable `verbose` mode and capture the sessions again, please. This will show the commands actually being sent down the command channel. I'd initially suggest it's something to do with restrictions mandated by your FTP Proxy ("Virtual Traffic Manager FTP Proxy", whatever that is).

Comment: I often use `ftp -d ...` when encountering these sorts of issues, so that the actual FTP commands sent (and responses received) are displayed.  Doing so for your Mac and Linux `ftp` commands might help reveal what's different between them, to see commands are acceptable to that FTP proxy, and which are not.